# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid `prisma.executeRaw()` invocation: ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid `prisma.executeRaw()` invocation:

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

my Stored procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.transfer_transactions(
initiated_by integer,
OUT transaction integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

```
    SELECT transaction_id INTO transaction
    FROM public."Transaction" 
    where initiated_by = initiated_by;

    SELECT transaction INTO transaction;

end;
```

$BODY$;

Calling the sp from nestjs prisma client

async create(createTransactionDto: CreateTransactionDto) {

const [callGetSequenceBlock, queryString] = await this.prisma.$transaction([
this.prisma.$executeRaw`CALL transfer_transactions(${login_id},@transaction);`,
this.prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT @transaction FROM DUAL;`,
]);

```
  return queryString;
```

}

error displayed  while executing API

Invalid `prisma.executeRaw()` invocation:

Raw query failed. Code: `42703`. Message: `column "transaction_idout" does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use the query raw, its function

const result: procedureResult = await this.prisma
.$queryRaw`CALL transfer_transactions( ${ct.initiated_by} )`;